# How to prove there exists such $C$ s.t. with high probability, $\max_i x_i^2 \leq \frac{C}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m x_i^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In this equation, $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$ are independent and have same distribution, e.g. Gaussian.

I can prove for a certain index like 1,
$$\mathbb{P} \left[ x_1^2 \geq \frac{C}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mx_i^2 \right] \leq \frac{m}{(m-1)C}-\frac{1}{m}$$ by using Markov's inequality and Jensen's inequality.

But this bound is not tight enough since if I apply union bound, $c$ would be $\Theta(m)$.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I observe that your probability bound is incorrect since $\frac{m}{(m-1)C} - \frac{1}{m}<0$ if $C$ is sufficiently large.  In general: Your question is unclear.  How does the title connect to the body of the question? What is scaling to infinity ($m$ or $C$)? What does “with high probability” mean?  What does $\max_i$ mean?  Is it $\max_{i\in \{1,…,m\}}$ or $\max_{i\in \{1,2\}}$ or $\max_{i\in\{1,…,\infty\}}$?

Comment: I observe that for any random variable $Y$ and any $\epsilon>0$ we have $$\left\{Y \geq \frac{C}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i\right\} 
\subseteq \left\{Y \geq CE[X_1^2] - \epsilon\right\} \cup \left\{\frac{C}{m}\sum_{i=1}^mX_i< CE[X_1^2]-\epsilon\right\}$$ and so $$P\left[Y\geq \frac{C}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i^2\right] \leq P\left[Y\geq CE[X_1^2] - \epsilon\right] + \underbrace{P\left[\frac{C}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i^2 < CE[X_1^2]-\epsilon\right]}_{\mbox{close to $0$ for fixed $C$ and large $m$}}$$ assuming $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. and $E[X_1^2]<\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. But it still doesn't work. By the way, if $C>m$ then the probability is meaningless which shows my inequality is correct.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, and what you claim "still doesn't work."  In all reasonable interpretations of your problem that I can guess, I believe the above _will work_.  Of course it would greatly help if you clarified your problem by answering my questions above concerning the connections between the title and body of your question, the meaning of $\max_i$, and so on.